# Тень  RadialGradient

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток.

Пытаюсь  получить  тень  круглой  кастомной  кнопки. Создаю под кнопкой  круг  и  отрисовываю  градиент:

```
mRadialGradient = new RadialGradient(getWidth()/2, (getHeight()/2)+1,r, new int[]{Color.argb(255,0,0,0),Color.argb(255,255,255,255)}, new float[]{0.2f, 0.9f}, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    mPaint.setShader(mRadialGradient);
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2,(getHeight()/3)+1,mPaint);
```

Пытаюсь  подкрутить переход  массивом, ничего не меняет. В  чем беда  сей  проблемы?

Заранее  благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел  ответ  в  исходниках  джава. Если  в  массив  цветов  добавить только  два  цвета, то  они  автоматически  распределятся  по  поверхности. Проблема  решилась  добавлением  в  массив  цветов  еще  одного  цвета